# http-security-filter doesn't work in mule

Tags: web-services, mule

I use Mule Server 3.3.0 CE, I generate this code:

```xml
 <mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.3/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.3/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.3/mule-pattern.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.3/mule-spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
        name="memory-dao" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="sepideh" password="16978413" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>


<pattern:web-service-proxy name="myService"
    wsdlLocation="http://ws.acme.com:6090/wsdl/weather-forecast">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8090/service">
        <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://ws.acme.com:6090/weather-forecast" />
</pattern:web-service-proxy>
```

I run this project and I have below exception:

```
ERROR 2012-11-27 14:31:25,456 [[web_service].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8090/service. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-54999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8090/service. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException)
org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter:160 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/security/UnauthorisedException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException: Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8090/sevice. Message payload is of type: String
    at org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.authenticateInbound(HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:160)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.authenticate(AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.java:58)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationFilter.java:56)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

New wsdl address show me but I can't use this address for create web service.
All of solution link to [this page](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/how_to_configure_spring_securitymanager_with_cxf_webservice), but I don't know how to change SoapUI to true value.
What should I change in my configuration?

Comment: Are you sending the authentication header?

Answer (score 3):

Posting this might helps some one. People who migrating the HTTP connectors from  Mule lower version to 3.6+ or 3.7( Because, I faced this error when upgrading). Please follow the link  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/configuring-the-spring-security-manager( We cannt configure `mule-realm` inside HTTP listener as like in version 3.3). When you try to hit it from SOAP UI, you will find the above error `Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session`. It is not the problem with Mule config file.Need to change  SOAPUI settings

2 ways to resolve this error:

Go to SOAPUI->File->Preference->HTTP settings-> enable the option `Authenticate Preemptively`
or
When setting the basic Auth In SOAPUI
Authorization->Basic -> Pre-emptive auth -> enable `Authenticate Pre-emptively`.
By default it will be 'Use global preference' which needs to be changed to `Authenticate Pre-emptively`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems related and the error you are getting is a red herring. Are you getting back a success response even if this is being logged?
http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5607